# Is there a style to apply that allows the legend to style each series as a button?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, legend

I'd like to style my legend so that each series looks like a button so it's more intuitive so users know they can click on a series and filter by each series.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Highcharts legend documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend).

Hopefully, you may find an available property that fits to your needs.

**Edit:** I would play with the [style property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.style)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the itemStyle property, which allows you to specify css for each legend item:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemStyle

You will also need to look at the itemHiddenStyle and itemHoverStyle properties:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemHiddenStyle
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemHoverStyle